# Can I substitute a beef round rump roast for brisket?

Tags: substitutions, beef, brisket

I am making a [slow cooker recipe that calls for beef brisket](http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/tangy-slow-cooker-brisket-50400000134223/). Unfortunately, my grocery store only had obnoxiously large cuts of brisket so I just grabbed a reasonably sized beef round rump roast. In the back of my head I thought I remembered that the two could be substituted for the other, but in trying to confirm that I'm coming up short.

Can I substitute a beef round rump roast for brisket? Do I need to adjust cooking time for the differing cut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much no, they are totally non-alike. The beauty of brisket is that it is *full* of connective tissue and other odd stuff that translates to succulence when cooked low and slow. Round is pretty much the opposite, it has very little in the way of *interest*.

Comment: I agree with @Jolenealaska, one is not a substitute for another. For this recipe I bet you'll get away with it - 7 hours may be overdoing it though. You won't get the same gelling effect from the breakdown of the connective tissue, so you may want to coat the rump in some flour and fry it off to get some thickening action.

Comment: Also if you're actually making this for passover as the recipe page implies, the round cannot be kosher.

Comment: I accidentally bought a Round Cut corned beef and followed the directions for slow cooker. It was so dry, nasty, and inedible. It had the texture of canned tuna. :(

Answer (score 1):

No. Rump roast is too lean, and does not have enough connective tissue. A Chuck roast would likely work in the recipe you linked in your question, as it bears more similarity to brisket in fat and connective tissue content.